# Composed Interface class

Tags: c++, inheritance, architecture, interface

Is there any right way to declare a class (interface) *Limit* that can be used as "composition" of both interfaces *Param* and *Lim*?

Base interface classes *Param* and *Lim*:

```
class Param {
public:
    virtual char *toStr(void) = 0;
};

class Lim {
public:
    virtual char *toStrL(void) = 0;
};
```

*ParamA* and *ParamB* implements interface *Param*:

```
class ParamA : public Param {
public:
    virtual char *toStr(void){ return "A";};    
};

class ParamB : public Param {
public:
    virtual char *toStr(void){ return "B";} 
};
```

*LimitA* and *LimitB* additionally implements *Lim*:

```
class LimitA : public ParamA, public Lim {
public:
    virtual char *toStrL(void){ return "LA";}
};

class LimitB : public ParamB, public Lim {
public:
    virtual char *toStrL(void){ return "LB";}
};
```

With *Limit* I would like to access methods *toStr()* and *toStrL()*

```
class Limit : public Param, public Lim {
};

void example(void){
    LimitA limitA;
    LimitB limitB;
    Limit *limit = polymorphic_downcast<Limit *>(&limitB);  // unable to type cast correctly
    char *str1 = limit->toStr();
    char *str2 = limit->toStrL();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The runtime can only know about derived classes you explicitly inherited from in the class declaration. You cannot insert extra classes later.

Comment: It looks like I have an architecture design problem. Maybe accessing _Param_ and _Lim_ methods together can be solved using some design pattern or some other way.